# how to add logo in google consent screen?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-oauth

I have created project in google developers console and now I want to set my logo in consent screen. I have logo on my computer and logo field on consent screen require URL, is there any way to set logo on my computer in consent screen? I have also tried uploading image on google drive and putting its share link in logo fild.

Answer (score 11):

You do need to use a URL, you can use Google Drive as a host , but you have to reformat the URL that is handed to you

You may have a url that looks like this
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5vVIFW9BJ_lb2k0SV9oUV9TSEU/view?usp=sharing

You need to change it to

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B5vVIFW9BJ_lb2k0SV9oUV9TSEU

Comment: Thank you!
Also, I didn't notice the change in the url from "/file/d/" to "uc?id=" initially which is why it was not working for me (I only remove the last bit "/view?usp=sharing"). But then I paid more attention to your answer and was able to get it to work!

Comment: I had to change from 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=' to 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id='

Answer (score 2):

No you cant upload the file to the consent form.  The logo must be hosted online someplace.

Comment: is there any way around?

Comment: Not really.  Put the picture on Google Drive maybe set it public access might work. Add it to your Google plus again set to public.  Those are just random ideas I haven't tried either.  If either idea works post back for anyone else with this problem.

Comment: yeah I am trying all the ways.. I have added Product Name and Home Url but when I run my application none of it is getting on consent screen... I just dont understand why?

Comment: The reason is that they don't want to store your file.  And it has to be there for the User to see when they authenticate. Think of how many pictures Google would have floating around if they had to store everyone's product pictures.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @DalmTo. The logo must be hosted online. But yes, you can configure the location by giving an address in "Projects > APIs and Auth > Consent Screen > Product Logo".

The maximum size is 120*120px.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded my icon to my AWS /var/www site, and entered the address in the Google console 'consent screen', and it worked.  Looks like it needs a publicly accessible http link for this.