# Google Developer Console - Consent Screen - Custom Product Logo Doesn't Work

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

In the Google Developer Console, Consent Screen, under Product Logo I added the URL to an image that's 120 x 120 px size in png format but the preview shows a broken link icon in the upper left corner and my image doesn't show.

I've confirmed the image is in a public URL and can access it directly.  I've also tried both png and jpg but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!
Peter

Comment: It looks like the problem is that the URL of the image is a ".ninja" TLD which apparently Google doesn't like.  I had to move the image to a site with a ".com".  This seems to be a bug and I'd love it if someone could let me know where I can report this to get fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Just had this same issue, tryed from my .services domain in all formats but showed nothing but a broken image.

Tryed it on my .com domain and worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with my .team url.

Fix was to use Google Drive to store the image.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31541822/418057

Comment: For me, drive.google.com didn't work either - I had to use AWS S3.

Answer (score 0):

Use the link of your domain e.g https://sokouhuru.com/image/uploadicon.png. That worked for me

Comment: @JayBhalani That is not meant to be an active link. He is showing the url as an example